# how to grep for complete words between whitespaces?

Tags: grep, whitespace

I have a set of text files and a set of keywords that I need to find in those files. However, I am only interested in matching "complete words", that is strings between whotespaces. So for example, if I have text

```
line1: word1 word2,
line2: word3 word22
line3: word4 aword2
```

I want to get only line1 but not 2 or 3 if I search for `word2`. Also, I need to know the line where the matched occurred, so I can't turn each text file in a bag of words and search there.

Can I use grep for this? If so, how? Or are there better alternatives?

Also, will this work if I want to search for a phrase instead, for example

```
line1: word1 word word2,
line2: word3 word word22
line3: word4 wword word2
```

should produce only line1 if I want to search for "word word2"

Comment: Why would "word22" match word2 if "word2," doesn't?

Comment: You're right, thank you, my typo. Corrected

Comment: You say you want to match `strings between whotespaces` so would `word2` not match the first line since the only place it occurs is in the context of `word2,`, i.e. not surrounded by whitespace?

Comment: Maybe a "delimiter" would be a batter term than "whitespace"

Answer (score 3):

This is where you have `grep` for and all its options:

> **`-w, --word-regexp`**: Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line or preceded by a non-word constituent character.   Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
>
> **<sub>source: `man grep`</sub>**

```
$ grep -w word2 file
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like

```
grep -E "(^|\W)word2($|\W)" mytestfile.txt
```

The same thing should also work for your second scenario

```
grep -E "(^|\W)word word2($|\W)" mytestfile.txt
```

The -E is for extended-regexp (egrep). (^|\W) will match the beginning of a line or a non-alphanumeric character (^a-zA-Z0-9). ($|\W) will match the end of a line or a non-alaphnumeric character.

I tested this on OSX, but I think it will work generally on almost any system (GNU Grep has a -E option too).

Answer (score 0):

Beware, users of pcre2grep!  Use of -w option or \W in the regexp does not work well with accented characters.  For example, using "(^|\W)class($|\W)" results in the following 2 lines also being matched:

> "Verset déclassé",
>
> "Segment de verset déclassé",

As you can see from this example, the accented e is not considered to be a word-forming character.

(NB:  I am using pcre2grep 1022 - GNU grep 2.0d)